# Django: How to set DateField to only accept Today & Future dates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, datefield

I have been looking for ways to set my Django form to only accept dates that are today or days in the future. I currently have a jQuery datepicker on the frontend, but here is the form field to a modelform.

Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

```
date = forms.DateField(
    label=_("What day?"),
    widget=forms.TextInput(),
    required=True)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could add a `clean()` method in your form to ensure that the date is not in the past.

```
import datetime

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(...)

    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data['date']
        if date < datetime.date.today():
            raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
        return date
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: There is a bug in your answer, if "date < datetime.today():" raises a Typeerror. It should be: "from datetime import date"  // "if date < date.today():"   But thanks again, a big help

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

Another useful solution is to tie validation to fields using the validators keyword argument. This is a handy way of keeping your Form code clear and enabling reuse of validation logic. For e.g

```
def present_or_future_date(value):
    if value < datetime.date.today():
        raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
    return value

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField(...
                           validators=[present_or_future_date])
```

Comment: Nice and easy solution

Answer (score 4):

Found out [MinValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) works perfectly for dates as well.

```py
import datetime
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.db import models

...

some_date = models.DateField(validators=[MinValueValidator(datetime.date.today)])
```

Comment: The Djangest way!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Django 1.2+ and your model will always force this rule, you can also take a look at [model validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects). The advantage will be that any modelform based on the model will use this validation automatically.