# django models.DateField prevent past

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am looking for ways to prevent user from entering past dates in in django admin page. Something like this:

[Django: How to set DateField to only accept Today & Future dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941974/django-how-to-set-datefield-to-only-accept-today-future-dates)

My model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do this is a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/). For example:

```
def validate_date(date):
    if date < timezone.now().date():
        raise ValidationError("Date cannot be in the past")
```

That function will determine whether a particular input value is acceptable, then you can add the validator to the model field like so:

```
date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None, validators=[validate_date])
```

Comment: According to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/#writing-validators), shouldn't a validator raise a  `ValidationError`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a validation in forms.py file to make sure that the entered date is not older than the current date. So, even if someone tries to enter a older date the user would get an error. Hope it works for you.