# can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am Building a BlogApp and I am stuck on an Error. I tried many times and tried many answers but nothing solved my error.

```
def validate_date(date_added):
    if date_added < timezone.now().date():
        raise ValidationError("Date cannot be in the past")

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=timezone.now,validators=[validate_date])
```

**The Work of this Function**

Work of this function is to prevent past date as a input.

**The Problem**

Whenever i try to make a new blogpost and try to add the past date then it is keep showing me :-

> can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

**What have i tried**

I tried many answers like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239315/cant-compare-datetime-datetime-to-datetime-date) but nothing worked for me.

I don't know what is wrong in this code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: As i mentioned in my Question that the link you gave me was not helpful for me.

Comment: @Program Ok but the answers you've got are the same as the one you've linked: using `datetime.date()`. This is the obvious answer. If this doesn't work, show us how you're applying this solution and what error message you're getting. Otherwise people will suggest the same thing.

Comment: It was two `.date() and .now().date()` so i didn't notice one in the previous. They both are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the left operand to a date as well, so:

```
def validate_date(date_added):
    #               ↓ convert to a date 
    if date_added.date() < timezone.now().date():
        raise ValidationError('Date cannot be in the past')
```

or if the timestamp should not be in the past (both date and time), then we compare the `datetime` objects:

```
def validate_date(date_added):
    if date_added < timezone.now():
        raise ValidationError('Date cannot be in the past')
```

Comment: The error is gone but new error is saying `'<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.date'`

Comment: But you need to *call* `.date`, so not `.date`, but `.date()`.

Comment: When i make a new `blog_post` of `now time` then it does not any error BUT when i change the` time into past` then it is showing me `The Post could not be created because the data didn't validate.` BUT it should show me the `ValidationError`. Please help me in this

Comment: @Progam: but then it is not the date that should be in the past, but the entire datetime, so `date_added < timezone.now()`.

Comment: I changed as you said BUT it is still showing that error.

Comment: @Progam: hold on, but what do you mean with show me the validation error? It shows it in the form right? A `ValidationError` is treated by the form. It is "catched" by the form and will not raise to the view level.

Comment: BUT I did according to this :-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002600/django-models-datefield-prevent-past AND it is saying that its in models

Comment: Django models do not validate by default. Only forms will do that for performance purposes. If you want to validate a model object, you call `.full_clean()`, so `mymodelobject.full_clean()`.

Comment: When i try to input past date in admin then it is showing `Validation Error` Correctly.

Comment: @Progam: and if you work with a `ModelForm`, it will also show the validation error.

Comment: Thanks Willem for your help

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be done by converting `datetime` object to `date` object using `.date()` method on any `datetime` object.

like the following

```py
date_added.date()
```